# BeautifulSoup on multiple .html files

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, text-files, extract

I'm trying to extract information between fixed tags with BeautifulSoup by using the model suggested here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27620077/3635159)

I have a lot of `.html` files in my folder and I want to save results obtained with a BeautifulSoup script into another folder in the form of individual `.txt` files. These `.txt` files should have the same name as original files but would contain only extracted content. The script I wrote (see below) processes files successfully but does not write extracted bits out to individual files.

```
import os
import glob
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

dir_path = "C:My_folder\\tmp\\"

for file_name in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_path, "*.html")):
    my_data = (file_name)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(my_data, "r").read())
    for i in soup.select('font[color="#FF0000"]'):
        print(i.text)
        file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
        text = open(file_path, mode='r').read()
        results = i.text
        results_dir = "C:\\My_folder\\tmp\\working"
        results_file = file_name[:-4] + 'txt'
        file_path = os.path.join(results_dir, results_file)
        open(file_path, mode='w', encoding='UTF-8').write(results)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glob returns full paths. You are re-opening the file for each `font` element you find, replacing the contents of the file. Move opening of the file *outside* the loop; you should really use files as context managers (with the `with` statement) to ensure they are closed properly again too:

```
import glob
import os.path
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

dir_path = r"C:\My_folder\tmp"
results_dir = r"C:\My_folder\tmp\working"

for file_name in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_path, "*.html")):
    with open(file_name) as html_file:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file)

    results_file = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0] + '.txt'
    with open(os.path.join(results_dir, results_file), 'w') as outfile:        
        for i in soup.select('font[color="#FF0000"]'):
            print(i.text)
            outfile.write(i.text + '\n')
```

Comment: @meshfields thanks for point that out; I must’ve forgotten to join the base filename to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob
import os
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

input_dir = "/home/infogrid/Desktop/Work/stack_over/input/"
#- Already Present on system.
output_dir = "/home/infogrid/Desktop/Work/stack_over/output/"

for file_name in glob.glob(input_dir+ "*.html"):
    with open(file_name) as fp:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(fp)
        results_file = "%s%s.txt"%(output_dir, os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_name))[0])
        tmp = [i.text for i in soup.findAll('font') if i.get("color")=="#FF0000"]
        with open(results_file, 'w') as fp:        
            print "\n".join(tmp)
            fp.write("\n".join(tmp))
```

Comment: This works as well. I like it that there are more than one way to do perform the same task. Thanks for your suggestion. It's a shame there is no option on `Stackflow` to accept both solutions.